# How to set auto generated meta fields for history table in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-simple-history

#### Sample Model

```
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords()

class Sample(models.Model):
  company = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)  
  history = HistoricalRecords()
```

In the above model,I have used the `HistoricalRecords` from [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) to keep a history of changes to each instance of `Sample`

#### The problem

`history_user` is failing to populate with the error message: `**Error** : 1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails,REFERENCES auth_user (id)`

How can I set the `history_change_reason` and `history_user_id` in `HistoricalRecords()` instances?

EDIT: Have tried this solution : [link](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#using-history-user-to-record-which-user-changed-a-model)

Comment: Can you show the implementation of how you are handling the change reason (or other auto populated fields)?

If you fill that from form data then you can populate the `history_user_id` in the `PUT` or `POST` request

Comment: @robotHamster Problem not in api side calling,While saving into db.Facing issue of foregin key.I have updated question Can you check

Comment: I need to see the `HistoricalRecords()` definition, and the way your view is handling the request. The foreign key constraint is probably failing because you're not supplying some information when the `save` method is called (whether it is called internally or you are explicitly calling it)

Comment: I can see you're using `django-simple-history` now. Did you include the middleware mentioned [here](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#settings) ?

Comment: @robotHamster That also, i tried but still i am getting the same problem

Comment: @Arpit what version of simple history are you using? What database?

Comment: @Ross Django-simple-history : 1.9.0

Comment: Try updating to the most recent version of django-simple-history. Also, are you using MySQL? @Arpit